# Till what number is finding the divisors of a given number possible in under 5 seconds

Tags: algorithm, division, integer-division

I am given a number `n <= 10^85`, I want to compute all of the divisors for the given `n`.

Till what number can I compute all of the divisors in under `5` seconds?

I am aware that the execution time of whatever algorithm is chosen depends on the hardware it is run on. Assume that it is run on an avarage developers pc, I am not expecting an exact number up to which I can compute the divisors, a rough estimate is sufficient.

I looked at several algorithms for finding the divisors and convinced my self that the answer must be `< 10^85`.

[The algorithm I looked at.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Parameters_from_realistic_example)

[How I tried to estimate the time](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(1.5*sqrt(ln(n)*ln(ln(n)))),%20n%20%3D%2010%5E85) (I used the running time of the algorithm above)

Comment: Why? (Please don't answer and delete your comment if you are trying to be funny)

Answer (score 1):

Your first link says that it took 35 minutes for a 1.6 GHz UltraSparc III to factor a 267-bit semiprime. A 267-bit number is less than 10<sup>81</sup>, so it is four orders of magnitude smaller than 10<sup>85</sup>. The 1.6 GHz UltraSparc is not a typical desktop machine, at least not where I live, but we can suppose that msieve running on a typical desktop machine will have similar performance. Unless you feel that you can reimplement msieve several thousand times as fast, it seems unlikely that you could factor a 85-digit number in less than 5 seconds.

For what it's worth, on my core-i5 laptop msieve took 124 seconds to factor the 76-digit semiprime 1031024382763741345720693024144503046286361588371249770826450615723688608887, which is the product of two 38-digit primes. In 5 seconds, it was able to do the 62-digit semiprime 7308332279578159953175572146691794473667384671982397578861693, which is the product of a 32-digit prime and a 30-digit prime. [Note 1]

Your second link -- "how to estimate the time" -- is meaningless. The time estimate is not measured in any particular units; it is simply an indication of growth rate. If an algorithm runs in Θ(f(n)) and you compute f(n) as 1000 (or 8.61036E20), you know essentially nothing: The algorithm could take 1000 nanoseconds or it could take 1000 years.

#### Notes

1. I found those semiprimes by using msieve to factor 20 random 128-bit numbers, which gave me six primes with 30 or more decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my attempt to calculate the actual running time with the asymptotic bound, that was silly:p  For future reference, I found what I was looking for here: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/factint/doc/chap4.html